# Object Detection MASK RCNN only for 2 classes

Tags: object-detection

I use (https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) MASKRCNN for object detection and everything works fine. Is there a way to detect only certain objects? There are more than 80 classes of which I only need 2 pieces (like car and person). I would like to have the remaining classes not detected. How can they be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using the default pre-trained coco model for detection which comes with 80 classes. You can train your own model.
First of all you have to use VIA (VGG image annotator) to label the classes you want to predict.
Once that is done, you have to make some changes to the code of the model. For example, if you are using the file **"balloon.py"**, you have to add classes, make some changes in ***load_mask()*** function and few other parts of the codes. After that you can start training your model, then use for detection and segmentation.

Yes, and for VIA, try using the version **1.0.0** as the format of the **.json** file is slightly changed in in the updated versions, which generally makes them incompatible with training on your custom data sets.

Check one example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuUSG.jpg)

Comment: I wish I saw this earlier as I had  annotated almost 300 frames from a tennis TV broadcast for ball location.  By the way, can I use circle or do I have to use polygon? @Adn, what shape did you use?

Comment: I used the polygon shape but you can use any shape to annotate. Even using circle will do as it points out the location of the object just like any other shapes

Comment: Would you happen to have a github repo?  Because my object of interest is so small (tennis ball on broadcast TV tennis matches), I tried using the landmark annotation which also gives x, y and using `skimage.draw.circle_perimeter()` in `load_mask` but my bounding box and masks are way off target.  It might be my dataset though...

Comment: You can use any shape to annotate